# Javascript - add hash in URL with "onscroll" to create browser history (works with Firefox, not with Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser-history

I'm trying to achieve the following thing:

- a page is loaded with a hashtag (ex: #loaded)
- when the user start to scroll (on scroll event) that page, a new entry with another hash is created (ex: #reading)
- when the user goes back in history, it should see the #loaded hash

This seems pretty simple to do but there is a trick with Chrome that I don't understand.

Here is the code:

```
current_hash = window.location.hash;
if (current_hash == "#loaded")
    {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", checkScroll);
    }

function checkScroll() 
    {
        original_url = window.location.href;
        clean_url = original_url.split('?')[0];
        clean_url = clean_url.split('#')[0];
                
        var stateObj = { page: "scrolled" };
        var newUrl = clean_url + "#reading";
        history.pushState(stateObj, "", newUrl);

        window.removeEventListener("scroll", checkScroll);

    }
```

I have added a hash listener in the body tag:

```
<body onhashchange="manageHash()">
```

and here is the function:

```
function manageHash()
    {

        switch(window.location.hash)
            {
                case "#reading":
                    console.log("started reading");
                    // do something
                break;
                
                case "#loaded":
                    console.log("back to loaded");
                    // do something else
                break;
            }
        
    }
```

When I access the page with #loaded and if I scroll, I see the #reading in the URL but in Firefox I can hit the back button but not with Chrome. The first time I fired the code in Chrome it worked and the second time I fired it without changing anything to the code, it didn't work anymore. Chrome detects the scroll, changes the hash but does not create a new entry in the history anymore.

I'm a bit puzzled because I can run the code as many times I want on Firefox and it works. With Chrome it worked only once and I don't see any error in the console.

I know that user interaction is required to be able to create a browser entry but in my case, I have the onscroll behaviour that should do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you use `pushState()` to change your hash you should use the corresponding `popstate` event that emitted when you hit the browser back button:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event

Also the `hashchanged` event is available on `window`. So maybe binding the event on window would work in Chrome:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchanged', manageHash);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event

Comment: Thanks but for Popstate to work, in my understanding the back button should be clickable while on Chrome, the back button remains deaf.

Comment: @Laurent strange, when you change the url with any way it should be enabled... i'll check your case later with more effort if no any other answer arrives.

Comment: Thanks! This behaviour is specific to Chrome. If you manipulate browser history, you can't do it programmatically, it needs to be linked to user interaction. Scrolling is a valid interaction but for some reason it doesn't work. If I replace scroll by click it works but I have more chances to trigger the script with a scrolling behaviour than a click.